# Spring Boot Application add datasource at runtime?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I working on a project which uses Spring boot , Spring Data JPA and postgres .There is a problem that can't solve .

When my application start up ,The database not ready yet . It need  to add to application at runtime . But I also want to initialize a database using JPA.
just like  `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto：create-drop`，Unfortunately Initialize a database using JPA will happen at application startup.

My question is that how to delay spring data jpa DDL generation. now we can't add a datasource at application runtime.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. The AbstractRoutingDataSource  may be not suit for us, because we don't have a datasource at begin .
Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you talking about production?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I am sorry , I can't understand what you means

Comment: why you want to delay the creation of database?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa  beacause we need a mini project . The database require to add at runtime.

Comment: @AmerQarabsa The database not ready  when The mini project start up

Comment: since you are planning to use create-drop, this means jpa will prepare it for you

Comment: @AmerQarabsa Yes , If I want to use create-drop , how to delay jpa initialize behavior

Comment: during the startup the springboot autoconfiguration reads the property file and search for the configuration , if you want to delay (which i dont understand why would you want it ) you need to connect to database after contextrefreshevent

Comment: @AmerQarabsa Thanks you reply, If don't care about JPA ,Is there some way to add datasource in application runtime,just need  one datasource

Comment: yes you can autowire datasource to one of your configuration classes and you can use it after the application context is refreshed

Comment: You can instantiate the entity manager at any point of time. In run time how will you change the modelling to update DB (need to restart if any change in source code).

Comment: @PRATHAPS  Could you be a bit more specific ？ thank you very much

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I am a newcomer for spring boot, could you be a bit more specific. thank you very much

Comment: @tanghuailong check this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

Comment: Show us the code what have you tried so far with error logs. People here can help you out.

Comment: @PRATHAPS  There is no error. I just don't how to implement  it that the database add after application startup . yes I can do it by retry  datasource connection. I think it not a proper way . because database ready to need some time， maybe a long time

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I know this, But the DataSource bean can't ready ,because there is no database when the application startup . why should i don't create database , perhaps need to ask architects

Answer (score 1):

AbstractRoutingDataSource is not useful as it requires pre-configured datasources.
just check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515298/spring-add-datasource-at-runtime) stackoverflow question, it shows how you can add/remove datasources at runtime. While it doesn't support hibernate's delayed ddl creation but you can create database tables in runtime datasources using schema.sql and inserts some constants using data.sql.